# Why am i getting the TypeError?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, typeerror

Sorry before hand if this is a silly question, but I tried to figure out and unable to get it through

I have a dictionary named data of pandas dataframe, where
**data['class_size']** has the following data

```
CSD    SCHOOL CODE    SCHOOL NAME
1      M015           P.S. 015 Roberto Clemente
1      M019           P.S. 019 Asher Levy
1      M019           P.S. 019 Asher Levy
.      ....           ..........
.      ....           ..........
and many more
```

and i tried the following lambda function as [pandas.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a parameter to pad the CSD column with 0 if its length is 1

```
data['class_size']['padded_csd'] = data["class_size"]["CSD"].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(2) if len(str(x)) == 1 else x )
```

That did worked fine, but after using the concatenation, i.e.

```
data['class_size']['DBN'] = data['class_size']['padded_csd'] + data['class_size']['SCHOOL CODE']
```

I am getting the TypeError of

> unsupported operand type(s) for '+' 'int' and'str'

I even checked the type of both the columns "padded_csd" and "SCHOOL CODE", they both are strings then why is a TypeError there?

Thanks in advance for any help

**P.S. I know i can create a function and use there instead of the lambda and it is even working but for some reasons I really have to use the lambda function**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
data['class_size']['padded_csd'] = data["class_size"]["CSD"].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(2) if len(str(x)) == 1 else str(x) )  #Update else str(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532312/rakesh), it was really a silly one